# Issue downloading Files from Web App - ASP.NET Web Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, webforms

Currently I have an issue on an ASP.NET Web Form application, where some people are not able to get the fully downloaded file being requested.

The file does download fully sometimes, but other times it stays hanging after a certain amount of bytes, and eventually the browser seems to suggest a network error. Again I would like to emphasis sometimes it's fine, other times the download is just stuck and not responding. I have tried putting a try/catch but nothing is being returned.

I cannot replicate this on a test web server, it only happens on production which makes this issue more difficult to find.

It seems nothing passed the flush, statement is being executed when this happens. If it doesn't occur all is normal.

```
public void DownloadFile(byte[] fileImage, string fileName )
{
    if (fileImage == null) return;
    string fileExt = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    string disposition = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileExt);
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;   
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", disposition);
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileImage);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Is there a certain size threshold where this seems to be happening? For example, small files are downloading fine but large ones are not? Could be a network device such as a firewall or load balancer is imposing response limits.

Comment: Is the file over 4MB? The standard buffer is 4MB so it could be that problem. In the client browser console do users get an error messages?

Comment: It can range from 2mb - 30mb so fairly small to higher sizes considering . It can download the bigger files sometimes. The load balancer limits are set to about 1gb, so don't think it's that and I can't see anything obviously wrong with the firewall. There are no errors in the console window

Comment: Have you tried to put a Response.Close() between flush and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the issue was caused by a Load balancer and not the code. The manner in which the load balancer was handling SSL seemed to be the key thing that caused this. For now the solution was to offload SSL Handling to the Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

This could be from Network , try to open the app directly from the server and see if it happens again. you can also check the log for the requests that goes for server and see what http code they get after they deliver.
those was my experience , hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34845156)